# Change css of list item before an after the item that is being hovered over

Tags: html, css, list

I've created navigation menu for my website. Here's the html: (you can also view the sidebar menu at belairfinishing.com, its the menu on the left.)

```
<div><img src="../public/images/skystatic.jpg" id="LinkForBannerImage"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../public/Vibratory Process Examples.htm">Proccess Technology</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public/Mass_Finishing_Equipment_001.htm">Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public/Mass_Finishing_Media_Compounds_001.htm">Media &amp; Compounds</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public/Cleaners and Dryers.htm">Parts Cleaners &amp; Dryers</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public/Waste_Water_Treatment_Sollutions_001.htm">Waste Water Treatment</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public/Precious Metal Recovery.htm">Precious Metal Recovery</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public/Mass_Finishing_Consulting_001.htm">Consulting</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public/Mass_Finishing_Technical_Articles_001.htm">Technical Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public/Press_Release.htm">Press Releases</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.toolhoning.com">Toolhoning.com</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public/portal/index.html">Distributor Log In</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Basically what I would like to happen is that when you hover over one of the items, ONLY the items directly before an after that get a red border. So if someone were to hover over Consulting, then Technical Articles and Precious Metal Recovery will have red borders.

I've been looking this up all morning and haven't found anything that works. So far I've tried to use nth-child(-n) and nth-child(n) to get 1 above an 1 below but I can't get that to actually work. Am I messing up the syntax or is their a better solution for this problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The one below could be done with `li:hover + li`. However, the problem is that there is [no CSS previous sibling selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector).

Comment: You could use jQuery if it is available to you. If you can you can target the hovered `li` and use `.next('li')` and `.prev('li')` and then apply your style during the hover and remove it on the release.

Comment: @Press I'm unable to use jQuery for this problem. I'm limited to html and css only.

Comment: @JCOC611 Using li:hover + li method worked and allowed me to create a red border around the next li but this li still had the same white border that it normally does on top of the red border. Any idea why it still using the non-hover css when its being hovered over?

Comment: @TimothyMcGee - I'm still working on making it work with html and css alone. So, check back, I might update my answer. :)

Comment: If you figure out a way to use html an css alone let me know! I was able to get the jQuery to work but html an css alone would be a much better solution for my website. Thanks for the help so far though! :)

Comment: @TimothyMcGee - Yes, I think it is possible using :pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CSS you could only select the next element using the adjacent sibling selector(`+`), however CSS doesn't have a previous sibling selector.

This could be achieve using jQuery.

```js
$('li').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).next().find('a').addClass('highlight');
    $(this).prev().find('a').addClass('highlight');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).next().find('a').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).prev().find('a').removeClass('highlight')
  })
```

```css
#cssmenu {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background: #222;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a:hover {
  color: rosybrown;
}
.highlight {
  border-bottom: 4px solid rosybrown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="../public/index.htm">Home</a></li
    ><li><a href="../public/About_Bel_Air_Mass_Finishing.htm">About Us</a></li
    ><li><a href="../public/ContactForm.htm">Contact Us</a></li
    ><li><a href="../public/Bel_Air_Trade_Shows_Seminars.htm">Trade Shows</a></li
    ><li><a href="../public/Vibratory_Finishing_Workshop.htm">Vibratory Workshops</a></li
    ><li class="last"><a href="../public/Bel_Air_Directions_Facility.htm">Directions</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Edit**

You could also make it work using CSS alone.

The idea is to add a `:before` :pseudo-element to `a` on `:hover`, if the `a` is not a descendant of first `li` and `:after` :pseudo-element, if the `a` is not a descendant of the last `li`.

i.e, `li:not(:first-child) a:hover:before, li:not(:last-child) a:hover:after`.

In simple words, it won't add the line on the left if the `li` is the first element and won't add the line on the right if the `li` is the last element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background: #222;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a:hover {
  color: rosybrown;
}
li:not(:first-child) a:hover:before, li:not(:last-child) a:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  left: -100%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid rosybrown;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
li:not(:last-child) a:hover:after {
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="../public/index.htm">Home</a></li
    ><li><a href="../public/About_Bel_Air_Mass_Finishing.htm">About Us</a></li
    ><li><a href="../public/ContactForm.htm">Contact Us</a></li
    ><li><a href="../public/Bel_Air_Trade_Shows_Seminars.htm">Trade Shows</a></li
    ><li><a href="../public/Vibratory_Finishing_Workshop.htm">Vibratory Workshops</a></li
    ><li class="last"><a href="../public/Bel_Air_Directions_Facility.htm">Directions</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```